# how prepopulate the database and set the flag in core data to guarantee I insert objects into the database only once per installation of the app

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest, nspersistentstore

I need to prepopulate my database using core data, but need to set a flag that would indicate whether the app was launched for the first time after installation. Im not sure how to do this?

heres what I'm doing in my appDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];



DJ *djsInfo = [NSEntityDescription
 insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DJ"
 inManagedObjectContext:context];

    /*DJ *djsInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DJ"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];*/



djsInfo.name = @"DJ Smoke";
djsInfo.city = @"Chicago";
djsInfo.state = @"Illinois";
DJDetails *failedBankDetails = [NSEntityDescription
                                        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DJDetails"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:context];
//failedBankDetails.closeDate = [NSDate date];
//failedBankDetails.updateDate = [NSDate date];
failedBankDetails.zip = [NSNumber numberWithInt:12345];
failedBankDetails.info = djsInfo;
djsInfo.details = failedBankDetails;


NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the standard user default mechanism.

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                         objectForKey:@"ThisAppWasLaunchedBefore"]) {
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES 
                                           forKey:@"ThisAppWasLaunchedBefore"];
  // do one-time setup stuff
 }
```